# Encountering Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN when trying to connect to aws aurora postgresql through lambda function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm trying to query the AWS Aurora PostgreSQL database through lambda function but I am encountering Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN

I've setup my lambda function and database instance in the same VPC. I am currently trying to just establish a connection the DB with no luck. I've read that the connection string should not have '/' and I've made sure that the string does not have these

```
var pg = require('pg');

exports.handler = () => {
    var conn = new pg.Client("postgres://username:password@host:5432/postgres");
    conn.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
          console.error('Database connection failed: ' + err.stack);
          return;
        }

        console.log('Connected to database.');
      });

      conn.end();
};
```

I expected to see the 'Connected to database.' message but I'm getting Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN host host:5432 at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:56:26) instead

Comment: This looks like a problem with the DNS server: there is no DNS server, it is not configured properly, it is current unavailable. The problem can be temporarily, so you could retry later.

Comment: Is "host" in your actual connection string? You must use the actual hostname or IP address of the database server.

Comment: Yes i have an actual connection string that I use. I just used "host" for privacy concerns

Comment: @jfish Do you found any solution on this to prevent EAI_AGAIN error?

Comment: Hi any luck i am also facing the same issue. can you let me know how its resolved